# SwiftUI - How to close a fake Modal View - from the second view inside it, with a close button?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a tricky design. I'm trying to have a close button that from whatever views, inside a "fake" Modal View (fake cause it's full screen, thanks to a code that i found online), it's gonna close the Modal View.
Right now the close button is working in the first view that open in the modal view, but I need it to work also in the next views of the modal view, cause I have a flow inside this modal view to create an item.

This is the View from which I start ColorNewItemView, my fake Modal View.

```
struct RecapItemToAdd: View {

  @State var isPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
        
        VStack {
            
            Button(action: { withAnimation { self.isPresented.toggle()}}) {
            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                .resizable()
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .frame(width: 13, height: 17)
                .foregroundColor(UIManager.hLightGrey)
            }

        }
        
        ZStack {
             VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                 ColorNewItemView(isPresenteded: self.$isPresented)

                 Spacer()
               }


         }
         .background(Color.white)
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
         .offset(x: 0, y: self.isPresented ? 0 : UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame.height ?? 0)
    }

   }
 
}
```

Note: I know that "keyWindow" is deprecated but I don't know how to change it.

With ColorNewItemView starts my full screen Modal View. In this view the close button works.

```
   struct ColorNewItemView: View {

   @State var selection: Int? = nil

   @Binding var isPresenteded: Bool

      var body: some View {
      NavigationStackView {
         VStack(alignment: .center) {

          Button(action: {
                  self.isPresenteded = false
              }) {
                  Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                  .resizable()
                  .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                  .foregroundColor(UIManager.hBlueLight)
              }
    
    Text("First View")
            .font(UIManager.einaTitle)
            .foregroundColor(UIManager.hDarkBlue)
    
    
    Image("black-hoodie")
    .resizable()
    .renderingMode(.original)
    .frame(width: 245, height: 300)
    
    PushView(destination: Color2NewItemView(isPresenteded: self.$isPresenteded), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                  
                 Button(action: {self.selection = 1}) {
                 Text("Avanti")
                      .font(UIManager.einaButton)
                      .foregroundColor(.white)
                      .frame(width: 291, height: 43)

                      .background(UIManager.buttonGradient)
                      .cornerRadius(6)
                      .shadow(color: UIManager.hBlueShadow, radius: 7, x: 0.0, y: 6.0)
                 }
              }

        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Now I have the next view inside the Modal view, where the close button starts to stop working.

```
    struct Color2NewItemView: View {

    @Binding var isPresenteded: Bool
    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .center) {


                 Button(action: {
                       self.isPresenteded = false
                   }) {
                       Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                       .resizable()
                       .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                       .foregroundColor(UIManager.hBlueLight)
                   }

        Text("Second View")
                .font(UIManager.einaTitle)
                .foregroundColor(UIManager.hDarkBlue)


        Image("black-hoodie")
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .frame(width: 245, height: 300)


        PushView(destination: FabricNewItemView(isPresenteded: $isPresenteded), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {

                         Button(action: {self.selection = 1}) {
                         Text("Tessuto")
                              .font(UIManager.einaButton)
                              .foregroundColor(.white)
                              .frame(width: 291, height: 43)

                              .background(UIManager.buttonGradient)
                              .cornerRadius(6)
                              .shadow(color: UIManager.hBlueShadow, radius: 7, x: 0.0, y: 6.0)
                         }
        }

                        Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 18)


                    PopView{
                        Text("Back")
                        .font(UIManager.einaBodySemibold)
                        .foregroundColor(UIManager.hGrey)
                    }

        }
    }
}
```

Ps.
I had also to use a library called NavigationStack, since I have a custom back button on the bottom of the page, and the Navigation View doesn't let me pop back without using the back in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding can be lost on deep view hierarchy, so it is more appropriate to operate with it on the level it was received.

Here is possible approach using `EnvironmentKey` (by same idea as `presentationMode` works)

Introduce helper environment key which holds some closure

```
struct DismissModalKey: EnvironmentKey {

    typealias Value = () -> ()
    static let defaultValue = { }
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var dismissModal: DismissModalKey.Value {
        get {
            return self[DismissModalKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[DismissModalKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

so in your top modal view you can inject into hierarchy callback to dismiss

```
struct ColorNewItemView: View {

   @State var selection: Int? = nil
   @Binding var isPresented: Bool

   var body: some View {
      NavigationStackView {
          // ... other code
      }
      .environment(\.dismissModal, { self.isPresented = false} )   // << here !!
   }
}
```

thus this environment value now is available for all subviews, and you can use it as

```
struct Color2NewItemView: View {
   @Environment(\.dismissModal) var dismissModal
   
   @State var selection: Int? = nil

   var body: some View {
      VStack(alignment: .center) {
          Button(action: {
              self.dismissModal()       // << here !!
          }) {
      
      // ... other code
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not really working for me .. I literally just copy and past your code, do I have to customize it somehow?

Comment: Hmm... do you use UIViewController/UIHostingView bridging somewhere in between ColorNewItemView and Color2NewItemView in hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks! It works, I was having an other stupid little problem. My button was in the area of the navigation bar so I could't click on it, I set it to hidden and worked!